# ifconfig showing invalid ip address

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

I booted pretty old PC (HP d530) with latest (2015.06) Gentoo linux minimal cd. The next step I wanted to perform was to enable SSH server on this machine.

I ran `ifconfig` to see the ip address of my machine. For the interface enp5s2 (only availible except of "lo") the ip address is 169.254.xxx.xxx

I started dhcp client to obtain ip address from router. It exited successfully, ping started to work, but in `ifconfig` there is still the same old ip address.

My router assigned 192.168.0.xxx, the PC is accessible through this address, but I'am not able to see it in `ifconfig`.

Nothing unusual in dmesg.

Why `ifconfig` is showing fake ip address?

Comment: Please add the executed commands and complete output to your question.

Comment: And also the output of `ip a`, which shouldn't be different. A 169.254 address is a [zeroconf address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) implying something in your network configuration failed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found solution.

This was an ipv4ll address created because of failure of ipv6 address assignment from dhcp.

Correct ipv4 address was visible in `ip a`

After adding

```
noipv6
noipv4ll
```

to dhcpcd.conf everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a known deficiency of both the GNU inetutils `ifconfig` and the NET-3 net-tools `ifconfig` for a long time. If your interface has multiple IP version 4 addresses, as will be the case if it has both a DHCP-assigned one and a link-local one, those two `ifconfigs` will only show you one of the addresses, in this case the link-local one.  The GNU inetutils `ifconfig` moreover will not show you any IP version 6 addresses for the interface at all.

This has not been addressed in well over a decade in those tools.  People did make patches for this, including one back in 2009 for the NET-3 net-tools one.  It reached Bernd Eckenfels 4 years later, [who never accepted it](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/bugs/12/#0f06).

Having a second link-local IP version 4 address in 169.254.0.0/16 in addition to the "routable" one in 192.168.0.0/16 is not actually a problem for your network interface itself, and you *could* leave your system configured this way, with (as you observed) little to no ill-effect whatsoever, as long as *no more than one* network interface does this.  Aside from the surprise to you that your system *has* this address, and that it has a concomitant route and will bind local sockets to this address when trying to connect to *other* link-local addresses, it is really *only* a significant problem for *those two `ifconfig` tools*.

As you note, `ip` will show you all of the IPv4 addresses.

So too will my `ifconfig`.

## Further reading

- Erik Åldstedt Sund  (2006-03-28). *[ifconfig: reports wrong ip address](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=359676)*.  Debian bug #359676.
- Eduardo Ferro (2009-04-16). *[ifconfig: reports wrong ip address / initial patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=359676#41)*.  Debian bug #359676.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504084/5132