# ip vs ifconfig commands pros and cons

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ifconfig

At some point, in some teaching material (from Linux Foundation) on Linux that I came across, the following is mentioned:

> `ip` command is more versatile and more efficient than `ifconfig` because it uses **netlink** sockets rather than **ioctl** system calls.

Can anyone elaborate a bit on this because I cannot understand what's going on under the hood?

P.S. I am aware of [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/482596/ip-tools-vs-old-ifconfig) on those tools but it does not address this specific difference on how they operate

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `ifconfig` command on operating systems such as FreeBSD and OpenBSD was updated in line with the rest of the operating system.  It nowadays can configure all sorts of network interface settings on those operating systems, and handle a range of network protocols.  The BSDs provide `ioctl()` support for these things.

This did not happen in the Linux world.  There are, today, three `ifconfig` commands:

- `ifconfig` from [GNU inetutils](https://gnu.org/software/inetutils/)

  ```
  jdebp % inetutils-ifconfig -l
  enp14s0 enp15s0 lo
  jdebp % inetutils-ifconfig lo
  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.0.0.0
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packets:9087 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:9087 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
        RX bytes:51214341  TX bytes:51214341
  jdebp %
  ```

  `ifconfig` from [NET-3 net-tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/)

  ```
  jdebp % ifconfig -l
  ifconfig: option -l' not recognised.
  ifconfig:--help' gives usage information.
  jdebp % ifconfig lo
  lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
      inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
      inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
      inet6 ::2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x80<compat,global>
      inet6 fe80::  prefixlen 10  scopeid 0x20<link>
      loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
      RX packets 9087  bytes 51214341 (48.8 MiB)
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
      TX packets 9087  bytes 51214341 (48.8 MiB)
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  jdebp %
  ```

  `ifconfig` from (version 1.40 of) [the nosh toolset](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/)

  ```
  jdebp % ifconfig -l
  enp14s0 enp15s0 lo
  jdebp % ifconfig lo
  lo
      link up loopback running
      link address 00:00:00:00:00:00 bdaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00 
      inet4 address 127.0.0.1 prefixlen 8 bdaddr 127.0.0.1 
      inet4 address 127.53.0.1 prefixlen 8 bdaddr 127.255.255.255 
      inet6 address ::2 scope 0 prefixlen 128 
      inet6 address fe80:: scope 1 prefixlen 10 
      inet6 address ::1 scope 0 prefixlen 128
  jdebp % sudo ifconfig lo inet4 127.1.0.2 alias
  jdebp % sudo ifconfig lo inet6 ::3/128 alias
  jdebp % ifconfig lo
  lo
      link up loopback running
      link address 00:00:00:00:00:00 bdaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00 
      inet4 address 127.0.0.1 prefixlen 8 bdaddr 127.0.0.1 
      inet4 address 127.1.0.2 prefixlen 32 bdaddr 127.1.0.2 
      inet4 address 127.53.0.1 prefixlen 8 bdaddr 127.255.255.255 
      inet6 address ::3 scope 0 prefixlen 128 
      inet6 address ::2 scope 0 prefixlen 128 
      inet6 address fe80:: scope 1 prefixlen 10 
      inet6 address ::1 scope 0 prefixlen 128 
  jdebp %
  ```

As you can see, the GNU inetutils and NET-3 net-tools `ifconfig`s have some marked deficiencies, with respect to IPv6, with respect to interfaces that have multiple addresses, and with respect to functionality like `-l`.

The IPv6 problem is in part some missing code in the tools themselves.  But in the main it is caused by the fact that Linux does not (as other operating systems do) provide IPv6 functionality through the `ioctl()` interface.  It only lets programs see and manipulate IPv4 addresses through the networking `ioctl()`s.

Linux instead provides this functionality through a different interface, `send()` and `recv()` on a special, and somewhat odd, address family of sockets, `AF_NETLINK`.

The GNU and NET-3 `ifconfig`s *could* have been adjusted to use this new API.  The argument against doing so was that it was not portable to other operating systems, but these programs were in practice *already* not portable *anyway* so that was not much of an argument.

But they weren't adjusted, and remain as aforeshown to this day.  (Some people worked on them at various points over the years, but the improvements, sad to say, never made it into the programs.  For example:  [Bernd Eckenfels never accepted a patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/bugs/12/#0f06)  that added some netlink API capability to NET-3 net-tools `ifconfig`, 4 years after the patch had been written.)

Instead, some people completely reinvented the toolset as an `ip` command, which used the new Linux API, had a different syntax, and combined several other functions behind a fashionable `command subcommand`-style interface.

I needed an `ifconfig` that had the command-line syntax and output style of the FreeBSD `ifconfig` (which neither the GNU nor the NET-3 `ifconfig` has, and which `ip` most certainly does not have).  So I wrote one.  As proof that one could write an `ifconfig` that uses the netlink API on Linux, it does.

So the received wisdom about `ifconfig`, such as what you quote, is not really true any more.  It is *now untrue* to say that "`ifconfig` does not use netlink.".  The blanket that covered two does not cover three.

It *has always been* untrue to say that "netlink is more efficient".  For the tasks that one does with `ifconfig`, there isn't really much in it when it comes to efficiency between the netlink API and the `ioctl()` API.  One makes pretty much the same number of API calls for any given task.

Indeed, each API call is *two* system calls in the netlink case, as opposed to one in the `ioctl()` system.  And arguably the netlink API has the disadvantage that on a heavily-used system it explicitly incorporates the possibility of the tool never receiving an acknowledgement message informing it of the result of the API call.

It is, furthermore, untrue to say that `ip` is "more versatile" than the GNU and NET-3 `ifconfig`s *because it uses netlink*.  It is more versatile because it does more tasks, doing things in one big program that one would do with separate programs *other than* `ifconfig`.  It is not more versatile simply by dint of the API that it uses internally for performing those extra tasks.  There's nothing inherent to the API about this.  One could write an all-in-one tool that used the FreeBSD `ioctl()` API, for example, and equally well state that it is "more versatile" than the individual `ifconfig`, `route`, `arp`, and `ndp` commands.

One could write `route`, `arp`, and `ndp` commands for Linux that used the netlink API, too.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`ifconfig`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ifconfig.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Eduardo Ferro (2009-04-16). *[ifconfig: reports wrong ip address / initial patch](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=359676#41)*.  Debian bug #359676.

Comment: I think you're reading too much into the "more versatile" claim. IMHO it only says that netlink is what makes `ip` more versatile, because all kinds of cool features are simply impossible to do using ioctls on Linux (because the ioctls are not there and likely will never be).

Comment: "netlink is what makes ip more versatile" is the same as "ip is more versatile because it uses netlink", which is _right there in the question_.

Answer (score 16):

The standard `ifconfig` we have in many distributions is deprecated for several reasons. Talks in a outdated and limited way with the kernel, and in fact, does not understand anymore all the network configurations. You won't be able to manipulate some network configurations such  `ifconfig` versions that you are able to do with `ip`. In addition, the `ifconfig` support for network namespaces is limited.

As an anecdotal tale, I found interface IP alias that are only visible in `ip` and not in SuSE `ifconfig`.

As for the differences under the hood: From [ifconfig vs ip: What’s Difference and Comparing Network Configuration](https://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-vs-ip-command-comparing-network-configuration/)

> Although `ip` might seem a bit complex at first site but it is much
>   broader in functionality than ifconfig. It is functionally organized
>   on two layers of Networking Stack i.e. Layer 2 (Link Layer), Layer 3
>   (IP Layer) and does the work of all the above mentioned commands from
>   net-tools package.
>
> While `ifconfig` mostly displays or modifies the interfaces of a system,
>   this command is capable of doing following tasks:
>
> - Displaying or Modifying Interface properties.
> - Adding, Removing ARP Cache entries along creating new Static ARP entry
>     for a host.
> - Displaying MAC addresses associated with all the interfaces.
> - Displaying and modifying kernel routing tables.
>
> One of the main highlight which separates it from its ancient
>   counterpart ifconfig is that latter uses ioctl for network
>   configuration, which is a less appreciated way of interaction with
>   kernel while former takes advantage of netlink socket mechanism for
>   the same which is a much more flexible successor of ioctl for
>   inter-communication between kernel and user space using rtnetlink
>   (which adds networking environment manipulation capability).

About the use/advantages of netlink: From [LJ - Kernel Korner - Why and How to Use Netlink Socket](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7356)

> Netlink socket is a special IPC used for transferring information
>   between kernel and user-space processes. It provides a full-duplex
>   communication link between the two by way of standard socket APIs for
>   user-space processes and a special kernel API for kernel modules.
>   Netlink socket uses the address family AF_NETLINK.
>
> .....
>
> Why do the above features use netlink instead of system calls, ioctls
>   or proc filesystems for communication between user and kernel worlds?
>   It is a nontrivial task to add system calls, ioctls or proc files for
>   new features; we risk polluting the kernel and damaging the stability
>   of the system. Netlink socket is simple, though: only a constant, the
>   protocol type, needs to be added to netlink.h. Then, the kernel module
>   and application can talk using socket-style APIs immediately.
>
> ....
>
> Netlink socket is a flexible interface for communication between
>   user-space applications and kernel modules. It provides an easy-to-use
>   socket API to both applications and the kernel. It provides advanced
>   communication features, such as full-duplex, buffered I/O, multicast
>   and asynchronous communication, which are absent in other
>   kernel/user-space IPCs.